# I need to implement a java program with synchronised methods but I can't avoid deadlock

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

This is the exercise's request:

- there are 3 rooms S1, S2, S3 with maximum capacity 20, 15, 10
- N people are trying to enter in the rooms and if the rooms are full wait
- at the first access each person tries entering in S1 and wait if it's
  full
- when a person has visited a room can enter another one, preferring a not full room and not visited room
- a person cannot exit from a rooms unless there are another available room
- a person ends his visit when has visited each room and print the sequence of visiting
- each person waits from 1 o 5 seconds before trying to change room
- every second the number of people in each room must be printed up to the end of all visits.

Use synchronised method in Java.

This is my code:

```
    package com.company;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        final int N = 30; //people number  (valore da cambiare anche all'attributo statico countPerson della classe Person)
        Guide guide = new Guide();
        Person [] persons = new Person[N];

        System.out.println("Starting visit");
        for(int i = 0; i<N; i++){
            persons[i] = new Person(i, guide);
            persons[i].start();
        }


        while(Person.countPerson!=0) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                System.out.println(" ");
                for (int i=1; i<4; i++){
                    System.out.print("There are "+ guide.countPeople(i)+" people in room number "+i+" ------");
                }
            }catch (InterruptedException e){
                System.out.println("Thread main interrupted");
            }
        }
    }
}

class Guide{
    private int S1=20;
    private int S2=15;
    private int S3=10;

    public synchronized int enterS1() throws InterruptedException{
        while (S1==0)
            wait();
        S1--;
        notifyAll();
        return 1;
    }

    public synchronized int enterS2() throws InterruptedException{
        while (S2==0)
            wait();
        S2--;
        notifyAll();
        return 2;
    }

    public synchronized int enterS3() throws InterruptedException{
        while (S3==0)
            wait();
        S3--;
        notifyAll();
        return 3;
    }

    public synchronized void exitRoom(int actualRoom){
        switch (actualRoom){
            case 1:{
                S1++;
                notifyAll();
                break;
            }
            case 2:{
                S2++;
                notifyAll();
                break;
            }
            case 3:{
                S3++;
                notifyAll();
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public int status(int room){
        switch (room){
            case 1:{
                return S1;
            }
            case 2:{
                return S2;
            }
            case 3:{
                return S3;
            }
            default:{
                return 999;
            }
        }
    }

    public int countPeople(int room){
        switch (room){
            case 1:{
                return 20-S1;
            }
            case 2:{
                return 15-S2;
            }
            case 3:{
                return 10-S3;
            }
            default:{
                return 999;
            }
        }
    }

}

class Person extends Thread{
    private int id;
    private Guide guide;
    private boolean[] visited;
    private int[] order;
    private int actualRoom;
    private boolean isFirstAccess;
    private boolean visitTerminated;
    private int counterOrder;
    public static int countPerson=30;

    public Person(int id, Guide guide) {
        this.id = id;
        this.guide = guide;
        this.visited = new boolean[3];
        this.order = new int[3];
        this.actualRoom = 0;
        this.isFirstAccess=true;
        this.visitTerminated = false;
        this.counterOrder=0;

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            visited[i] = false;
            order[i] = 0;
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (!visitTerminated){
            try {
                //start first access for this person
                while(isFirstAccess){
                    if(guide.status(1)!=0) {
                        actualRoom = guide.enterS1();
                        if (actualRoom == 1) {
                            isFirstAccess = false;
                            visited[0] = true;
                            order[counterOrder]=1;
                            counterOrder++;
                            Thread.sleep((int)(Math.random()*4001)+1000);
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        Thread.sleep((int)(Math.random()*4001)+1000);
                    }
                }
                //end first access for this person

                if(guide.status(2)!=0 /*&& actualRoom!=2 */&& !visited[1]){
                    guide.exitRoom(actualRoom);
                    actualRoom=guide.enterS2();
                    visited[1]=true;
                    order[counterOrder]=2;
                    counterOrder++;
                    Thread.sleep((int)(Math.random()*4001)+1000);

                } else if (guide.status(3)!=0 /*&& actualRoom!=3*/&& !visited[2]){
                    guide.exitRoom(actualRoom);
                    actualRoom=guide.enterS3();
                    visited[2]=true;
                    order[counterOrder]=3;
                    counterOrder++;
                    Thread.sleep((int)(Math.random()*4001)+1000);

                } else if(guide.status(1)!=0 /*&& actualRoom!=1*/){
                    guide.exitRoom(actualRoom);
                    actualRoom = guide.enterS1();
                    Thread.sleep((int)(Math.random()*4001)+1000);

                }else if(guide.status(2)!=0 /*&& actualRoom!=2*/){
                    guide.exitRoom(actualRoom);
                    actualRoom=guide.enterS2();
                    if(!visited[1]){
                        visited[1]=true;
                        order[counterOrder]=2;
                        counterOrder++;
                    }
                    Thread.sleep((int)(Math.random()*4001)+1000);

                } else if (guide.status(3)!=0 /*&& actualRoom!=3*/){
                    guide.exitRoom(actualRoom);
                    actualRoom=guide.enterS3();
                    if(!visited[2]){
                        visited[2]=true;
                        order[counterOrder]=3;
                        counterOrder++;
                    }
                    Thread.sleep((int)(Math.random()*4001)+1000);
                }


                if(visited[0] && visited[1] && visited[2]){
                    guide.exitRoom(actualRoom);
                    System.out.println("Person number "+this.id+" has terminated his visit. "+"Visiting order: "+order[0]+"-"+order[1]+"-"+order[2]);
                    visitTerminated=true;
                }
            }catch (InterruptedException e){
                System.out.println("Thread interrupted, people are leaving rooms ");
                guide.exitRoom(actualRoom);
            }
        }
        countPerson--;
    }
}
```

If N>50 my program enter in deadlock and I'm not able to fix it. Could you help me?
Thanks

Comment: This question is more a thing for code review. They could give you some helpfull pointers. This entire code is in need for a great rebuild. Especially concerning the Thread use.

Answer (score 1):

In your description you have the following capacities `S1=20, S2=15, S3=10`. This gives a total of 45 available spots. You also have a constraint that `a person cannot exit from a room unless there are another available room`.

When you set `N = 50` you fill up all rooms, and no-one is able to leave their current room as all other rooms are full. So yes - the program may hang when `N > 44`.

Thanks to @Robert for pointing out that the program still might terminate for `N > 44`.

Comment: I would not use "will" but it may happen.

Comment: That depends whether a person also waits 1-5 seconds before entering the first room, or they all tries to enter as soon as the program is started. If not the all rooms will be filled before the first person tries to change room.

Comment: At the beginning only S1 will fill-up: `at the first access each person tries entering in S1 and wait if it's
full`

Comment: @Robert you are correct, I missed that part. I'll update the answer.

Comment: You both are right, deadlock could occur if N>=45. Have you any idea to fix this deadlock problem? It can not be solved respecting all constraint ?

Comment: @Guido Lippi: The problem is not your code but the exercise description. It misses the possibility that two persons switch their rooms. Without that the deadlock is unavoidable at a certain point.

Comment: @GuidoLippi: As Roberts says, the problem description does not handle the scenario where all rooms are filled with people that all need to visit one or more rooms. To solve this the some of the constraints of the problem would need to be relaxed. E.g. by allowing two persons to swap rooms, although this still would not guarantee that the program would not hang, or by allowing for people to leave a room and and "wander the halls" until a spot opens in the room they need to visit.